# Select text by ContextMenu

Tags: android

I have a looong text in `TextView` in `ScrollView` and I want to make a function to tab on text and select current paragraph to add it in bookmarks, but I haven't any ideas how to do it, please somebody help me. I'm trying to get current positions, but I don't know how to slect text.

Comment: u can save text in clipboard by using ClipData & ClipboardManager see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: yes, but I want to auto-select paragraph, I dont know how to set cursor to current position in TextView to select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use new TextView for each paragraph, and let it impliment a click Listener

the code should look like this

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bubdle bundle) {
           super.onCreate(bundle);
           ScrollView view = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
           // String txt = getText from Somewhere
           String[] text = txt.split(".");
           for (String t : text) {
           TextView view = new TextView();
           view.setText(t);
           view.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
           view.addView(view);
           }


   }
```

Comment: Yes textViews are somewhat light weight views, as long as the text paragraphs are few ( less than 40 let's say) everything should be ok
more than that you would have to create your own custom views or use OpenGL